# Best Practices Ingesting JSON into BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

```
bq --location=US load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect ERIC_KOLOTYLUK_BQ_POC_DATASET.Test2 small_data_clean.jsonl
```

seems to work well if the JSON is very clean, but very fragile with abstruse diagnostics when the JSON is not very clean. *Well, the feature is still experimental, so no point in complaining.* For example, if JSON property names contain `-` characters, while these are valid JSON, they are not valid BigQuery Column Names.

My questions is, **are there some existing tools/utilities for ingesting generic JSON into BigQuery that works better than `--autodetect`?**

Presumably Google will improve `--autodetect` over time, but for now I am looking for any advice/experience people may have. I have already written some code to replace `-` with `_` in property names, so I was wondering if other people have similarly creates tools/utilities...

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned for a sample scenario, you have a JSON property that has "-" for a column name, however per this [Specifying a Schema Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names),

> A column name must contain **only** letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or
> underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore.

Any characters non-compliant with the above will result to error on creation of columns during the definition of schema.

On the other hand, when using `--autodetect`, [BigQuery's official documentation on Auto-Detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect) already has a disclaimer saying,

> When BigQuery detects schemas, it might, **on rare occasions**, change a
> field name to make it compatible with BigQuery SQL syntax.

Since there is no other tools yet available to auto-correct/format JSON data to fit the BigQuery requirements for schema definition, the best approach for this kind of scenario is to write a code to replace unwanted characters on JSON data's column names, in which you already did.

Comment: I was easily able to write code to clean up the JSON for BigQuery. Given schema auto-detect is still in Beta, I suspect Google will improve this, as it was very easy for me to do with a few lines of code.